# How to create Hotspot with a Broadcom bcm43228 wireless card?

Tags: broadcom

It seem impossible to configure this card to master mode.
I can creat ah-doc connection, but no other device can see it.
Anyone knows if this is doable and how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the same problem on hp t610 on Debian 11:
bcm43228 (wifi) works and I can create AP and others devices can see Debian's assess point. But noone can connect to it...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239888)